# List all branches of subfolders in directory with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, os.walk

I'm trying to create a list of all folders and sub folders and sub-sub (etc) folders in a directory. So far I've come up with this:

`roots = list(set([a[0] for a in tuple(os.walk(r"C:\example"))]))`

It's a bit slow though, mainly due to `os.walk` when there are many files in the directories. It seems like there must be a better way to determine this that skips looking at all the files as well as folders. Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the implementation of `os.walk`:

```
islink, join, isdir = path.islink, path.join, path.isdir

# We may not have read permission for top, in which case we can't
# get a list of the files the directory contains.  os.path.walk
# always suppressed the exception then, rather than blow up for a
# minor reason when (say) a thousand readable directories are still
# left to visit.  That logic is copied here.
try:
    # Note that listdir and error are globals in this module due
    # to earlier import-*.
    names = listdir(top)
except error, err:
    if onerror is not None:
        onerror(err)
    return

dirs, nondirs = [], []
for name in names:
    if isdir(join(top, name)):
        dirs.append(name)
    else:
        nondirs.append(name)  # not interesting

if topdown: # not inretesting
    yield top, dirs, nondirs
for name in dirs:
    new_path = join(top, name)
    if followlinks or not islink(new_path): # not interesting
        for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
            yield x
if not topdown: # not inretesting
    yield top, dirs, nondirs # not inretesting
```

I marked the lines which you can optimize with "not interesting". I think you may get a speedup if you use `followlinks = True` and adapt these lines to your needs.

Your line can be more optimal, too:

```
roots = list(set([a[0] for a in tuple(os.walk(r"C:\example"))]))
roots = [a[0] for a in os.walk(r"C:\example")]
```

So what you want to have is this:

```
import os
def directory_paths(root):
    isdir = os.path.isdir
    for entry in os.listdir(root):
        new_root = os.path.join(root, entry)
        if isdir(new_root):
            yield new_root
            for path in directory_paths(new_root):
                yield path
```